# table surounded by form

Tags: jsp, servlets

What is the right way to surround table (which has form inside) by another form or how to access variables inside table to pass them to checkout?

I have this:

```
out.println("<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN='CENTER'>"
                    + "<TR BGCOLOR='#FFAD00'>"
                    + "<TH>Title</TH><TH>Artist/Director</TH><TH>Price</TH><TH>Number</TH><TH>Total Cost</TH>");

            for (SimpleItem item : previousItems) {
                out.println("<TR>"
                        + "<TD>"+ item.getItemName() + "</TD>"
                        + "<TD>"+ item.getItemArtistDirector() + "</TD>"
                        + "<TD>"+ formatter.format(item.getItemPrice()) + "</TD>"
                        + "<TD>"+ "<FORM ACTION='OrderPage'>" 
                        + "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='title' VALUE='" + item.getItemName()+ "'>"
                        + "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='artistDirector' VALUE='" + item.getItemArtistDirector()+ "'>"
                        + "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='price' VALUE='" + item.getItemPrice()+ "'>"
                        + "<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='numItems' SIZE=3 VALUE='" + item.getItemCount() + "'>" + "<SMALL>"
                        + "<INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' VALUE='Update Order'>" + "</SMALL>"
                        + "</FORM>" + "</TD>"
                        + " <TD>"+ formatter.format(item.getTotalCost())+"</TD>"
                        );

            }

            out.println("</TABLE>");

            out.println("<form action='CheckOut.jsp'>");
            out.println("<big><center>");
            out.println("<input type = 'submit' value = 'Proceed to Checkout'>");
            out.println("</big></center>");
            out.println("</form>");
```

however the proceed to checkout doesn't pass any values which is obvious
so I have moved `out.println(<form action='CheckOut.jsp>)` and stick it before I create table, also I've try do something like `<table><proceed form><table>...<other form/>...</table></form></table>`

and when I surround table with this form update order stop working and instead of update item it takes me to JSP page

so mainly I want pass values of title, artistDirector and price to JSP page. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve it for inner form action I've used button instead input type submit and it works
                                                                 `"<button TYPE='SUBMIT' formaction = 'OrderPage'>Update Order</button>" + "</SMALL>"`